# mPDF can't create PDF file on hosting

Tags: php, mpdf

Im creating PDF on my localhost it works
[image]

but on public websites it doesn't and when I turn on `error_reporting();`
shows me

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /data/web/virtuals/115253/virtual/www/pdf/pd/index.php:9) in /data/web/virtuals/115253/virtual/www/pdf/pd/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 8297

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /data/web/virtuals/115253/virtual/www/pdf/pd/index.php:9) in /data/web/virtuals/115253/virtual/www/pdf/pd/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 1706
mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file
```

I'm using mPDF thank you

Comment: Now it returning error's with header

Comment: Show us that lines code, where it generating errors. Means code of line `8297` and `1706`

Comment: Do you have a `?>` at the end of your PHP files? If yes, are they followed by more than one newline?

Comment: You simply have output before outputting the PDF. Change return mode when you actually generate the PDF if you need output before the actual document.